# YouTube API list endpoint and sampling

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

regarding the /list API from Youtube: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

We have `search by keyword` operations.

Do these searches perform some sort of sampling or are they an exhaustive source of all items that match a search ?

Also, does this change between each available api version ?

We have a similar case for the Twitter API, in which case this is explicitly stated: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets
So it would be good to know it because I have clients who often question these things so we can properly document the capabilities we offer.

Thank you.

Comment: Provide some sample cases.

Comment: Hey @MauricioAriasOlave sorry I didn't understand, do you want me to provide samples or is that the answer to my question ?

Comment: yes, please provide samples in order to check the data you get when you do searches by keyword.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave you see, I don't think that applies here, I'm just asking about the behavior for the YouTube team, I followed the instructions here on their page to get support via StackOverFlow: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support.

I have tagget my question with the tags they monitor.

I don't see how providing samples will help with anything as I am questioning about the nature of how it works, and not about a particular result in any way.

Comment: For a specific programming question, this is the place. For a bug report or similar issue with YouTube Data API - use [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) - at the end of the page it says: `Something wrong? Send us a bug report!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking on issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/283208635 as the YouTube employee asked.